# Let $C = \{\frac{a}{b}|a\in A, b\in B)$. Prove that $\sup C=\frac{\sup A}{\inf B}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given $A,B \subseteq (1, 30).$

Let $C = \left\{\frac{a}{b}|a\in A, b\in B\right\}.$

Prove that $\sup C=\frac{\sup A}{\inf B}$

I know it seems trivial but I'm struggling with the formality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to slow down, Mister Bister, with posting nothing but Problem statement questions, claiming to know nothing, and making pleas for help.  It gets old, and you should know that to many such questions, and you risk being blocked from asking question.  Please improve this question: What is $\sup A$?  What is $\inf B$?  Please include some effort in your post, starting here.

Comment: Also, $(1, 30)$ is an interval (which is a subset of $\mathbb R$?)  So are A, B subsets of $(1, 30)$?  You say $A, B \in (1, 30)$.  That makes no sense, because the elements of $(1, 30)$ are all $x$ such that $1 \lt x \lt 30$.  Which, if $A, B \in (1, 30)$, then A, B are real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in A,B$ respectively, then $b\geq\inf B$ and hence $\dfrac{1}{b}\leq\dfrac{1}{\inf B}$. And $a\leq\sup A$, so $\dfrac{a}{b}\leq\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}$, this shows $\sup C\leq\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}$.

Given $\epsilon>0$ and find some $a,b\in A,B$ respectively such that $\sup A-\epsilon<a$ and $\inf B+\epsilon>b$, then $\dfrac{\sup A-\epsilon}{\inf B+\epsilon}<\dfrac{a}{b}\leq\sup C$. Now let $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, then $\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}\leq\sup C$.

For the last part, another way:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sup A-\epsilon}{\inf B+\epsilon}&<\sup C\\
b\sup A&<a\inf B+(a+b)\epsilon,
\end{align*}
and since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, then
\begin{align*}
b\sup A&\leq a\inf B\\
\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}&\leq\dfrac{a}{b},
\end{align*}
so $\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}\leq\sup C$.

Comment: Can you explain why this $\dfrac{\sup A}{\inf B}\leq\sup C$ can be concluded?

Comment: I used another method, it should be easy to follow now.

Comment: Thank you. It should be equal in the end right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Just do definitions.

If $c \in C$ then $c = \frac ab$ for some $a \in A$ and some $b \in B$.

Then $a \le \sup A$ and $b \ge \inf B$ so $\frac ab \le \frac {\sup A}{\inf B}$.  (Note:  This assumes $b > 0$ and $\inf B > 0$.)

So $ \frac {\sup A}{\inf B}$ is an upper bound of $C$.

If $0<  x <  \frac {\sup A}{\inf B}$ then $x*\inf B < {\sup A}$ so $x*\inf B$ is not an upper bound of $A$. so there exists and $\alpha \in A$ so that $x*\inf B < \alpha \le \sup A$. (Note: this assumes $\sup A > 0$.)

So $\inf B < \frac \alpha x$.  So $\frac \alpha x$ is not a lower bound of $B$.  So there exists a $\beta \in B$ so that $\beta < \frac \alpha x$.

So $x < \frac \alpha\beta \in C$.  (Note: this relies upon $x > 0$.)

So $x $ is not an upper bound of $C$.

So $\frac {\sup A}{\inf B}$ is the least upper bound of $C$.

(Note:  Don't need $A,B \subset (1,30)$ just need $A,B \subset \mathbb R^+$.)